# Is there an issue or performance trade off using lodash get() to access nested list

Tags: lodash

Is there an issue or performance tradeoff on one over the other in accessing the nested list using lodash get

example

> const tempObject = { li: { nestedLi: [1, 2] } };
>
> // Is this better
>   _.get(tempObject, 'li.nestedLi.0')
>
> // or is this better
>   _.get(tempObject, 'li.nestedLi[0]')

Answer (score 0):

You have more than few ways to get a value via `lodash`. All of these are valid:

```
const tempObject = { li: { nestedLi: [1, 2] } };

console.log(_.get(tempObject, 'li.nestedLi.0'))          // dot
console.log(_.get(tempObject, 'li.nestedLi[0]'))         // bracket
console.log(_.get(tempObject, ['li', 'nestedLi', '0']))  // array

console.log(_.result(tempObject, 'li.nestedLi.0'))  
console.log(_.result(tempObject, 'li.nestedLi[0]')) 
console.log(_.result(tempObject, ['li', 'nestedLi', '0']))
```

Differences performance wise between the `_.get` methods are insignificant.

This is [the base _.get implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.10/lodash.js#L3048):

```
function baseGet(object, path) {
  path = castPath(path, object);

  var index = 0,
      length = path.length;

  while (object != null && index < length) {
    object = object[toKey(path[index++])];
  }
  return (index && index == length) ? object : undefined;
}
```

Which basically converts the path to array and then uses `while` to walk the path. So actually you could say that using the array notation would save you some time since `castPath` does not have to `cast` it :)

This is the [castPath](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.10/lodash.js#L4475):

```
   function castPath(value, object) {
      if (isArray(value)) {
        return value;
      }
      return isKey(value, object) ? [value] : stringToPath(toString(value));
    }
```

The [**`_.result`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#result) would walk the path and check if there are functions among the way and if there are it will execute them and keep moving. Quite handy in the knockout scenarios since it saves you the usual `ko.unwrap` etc.